# CheckboxSelectionModel Grid in ExtJs : Cannot select check boxes in a grid panel, all rows will be checked when selecting the header checkbox

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid panel with CheckboxSelectionModel in my form. I am using ExtJs 3.4.This is my grid panel.

```
var selectModel = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();

var drop_pick_grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
store : dropPickGridStore,
cm : new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([ selectModel, {
    sortable : true,
    header : "Drop/Pick Loc",
    dataIndex : 'locationName',
    width : 170,
    renderer : function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex,
            colIndex, store) {
        var refColor = record.data.tourTypeColor;
        //console.log(record);
        metaData.attr = 'style="background-color:' + refColor + ';"';
        return record.get('locationName');
    }
}, {
    header : "Town/City",
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'city',
    width : 120
}, {
    header : "Address",
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'addr',
    width : 170
}, {
    header : "EST.Un/Load Time",
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'estimatedTime',
    width : 100
} ]),
sm : new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel(),
//width : 570,
//height : 390,
autoHeight : true,
autoWidth : true,
frame : true,
iconCls : 'icon-grid',
renderTo : document.body
});
```

This grid is loaded from postgresql database using Json.

```
var dropPickGridStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
fields : [ {
    name : 'locationCode'
}, {
    name : 'locationName'
}, {
    name : 'city'
}, {
    name : 'addr'
}, {
    name : 'estimatedTime'
}, {
    name : 'tourTypeColor'
} ],
root : 'dropPickLoc',
idProperty : 'locationCode',
//autoDestroy : true,
autoLoad : true,

proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    url : "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + projectName + "/"
            + "PendingDropPicks"

}),
reader : {
    type : 'json',
    root : 'dropPickLoc'
    //idProperty : 'locationName',
},
});
```

The grid is loaded successfully. The problem is I cannot check check boxex in the grid but it can select all the rows by clicking the header check box. Why it cannot check each and every row separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the same selection model object in the `columns` and the `selModel` config. Here, you're creating two distinct instances of `Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel`.

Replace this line:

```
sm: new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel(),
```

With this:

```
sm: selectModel,
```

Comment: rixo, I've already tried this. But then I cannot check any of check box of the grid. I can only chech the header check box

Comment: Is there are any mistakes in my dropPickGridStore

Comment: There's no mistake that I can spot in your store... It's surprising that my proposed fix doesn't work for you. For the fiddle I posted in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21019258/1387519), I started with the code from this one, and I just changed `sm` to use the same instance to make it work. If you can reproduce your issue in a fiddle, I think I'll be able to tell you more...

Comment: This works. I have to define select model for both grids seperately.Thanx for your valuable guidelines rixo